# How to use pandas to do SQL-style inner join using alias table names

Tags: python, pandas

How do I construct a pandas dataset using inner-join on multiple statements where I need to use table alias (x1, x2)

My assumption is on merge statement, I need to somehow append the column name to with x1_ and x2_ ...but only see examples on stackoverflow joining on one condition

I need the prefix because I need to nest this dataset further

```
select * from data where cpty_type = 'INTERBRANCH'and (expiryDate >= '2017-04-18 00:00:00.000')) x1
inner join 
(select * from data where cpty_type = 'INTERBRANCH' and (expiryDate >= '2017-04-18 00:00:00.000')) x2
on (x1.extCptyID = x2.baseCptyID
and x1.baseCptyID = x2.extCptyID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) has a suffixes argument that can append for overlapping column names.

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'id':pd.np.arange(1,10),'col1':list('ABCDEFGHI')})
print(df_A)

  col1  id
0    A   1
1    B   2
2    C   3
3    D   4
4    E   5
5    F   6
6    G   7
7    H   8
8    I   9

df_B = pd.DataFrame({'id':pd.np.arange(1,10),'col1':list('QWERTYUIO')})
print(df_B)  

  col1  id
0    Q   1
1    W   2
2    E   3
3    R   4
4    T   5
5    Y   6
6    U   7
7    I   8
8    O   9

pd.merge(df_A,df_B, on=['id'], suffixes=('_A','_B'))
```

Output:

```
  col1_A  id col1_B
0      A   1      Q
1      B   2      W
2      C   3      E
3      D   4      R
4      E   5      T
5      F   6      Y
6      G   7      U
7      H   8      I
8      I   9      O
```